# IFS using multiple date ranges (Excel Functions)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use an Excel IFS function but can't seem to make this work, I keep returning a #NAME? error.

I've got the date of a due piece of work in column G and already have it conditional formatted to be Green if due in over 28 days, Orange if due within 28 days and Red if overdue. I then want to return a text value in column E with the text 'Not Due' 'Due' and 'Overdue' respectively.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: IFS() is only available in Office 365 Excel.  You probably have and older version, You will need to use nested IF

Comment: 1. `IFS` is a function for limited 'flavors' of xl2016. 2. Can you use it on a worksheet? Use `Lookup` instead. 3. Show the formula that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting three IF statements or using IFS, use LOOKUP.

```
=LOOKUP(G2-F$1, {-1E+99,0,28}, {"Overdue","Due","Not Due"})
```

[image]